# Excel 2013 generates empty content.MSO log file

Tags: excel, xslt, windows-8.1, office-2013

Windows 8.1 and
Office 2013

If I try to open an invalid spreadsheet XML file in Excel a pop-up notification gives a brief explanation of the problem and a points to a detailed log file in the Content.MSO folder. However, when I open the detailed log file, it is empty. Earlier versions of Excel and/or Windows populated this log file with each issue encountered.

What is preventing this log file from being populated?

Comment: I have experienced the same issue, in the beginning I used Git Bash run in Admin mode to visit the specified location - and I saw the logs. But now even that doesn't work for me anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of the KB number but a fix for Office 2013 related to this issue was pushed through Windows Update around 12/12/2014. Error logging appears to be working again.